# Como fazer um Ajuda equivalente ao Microsoft Help Viewer, mas no Visual Studio 2012/2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-help-viewer

Queria fazer uma Ajuda para um sistema de automação comercial que criei, que fosse no estilo do ajuda do WinRAR, e que fosse offline. Mas aparentemente de acordo com o artigo [Microsoft Help Viewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Help_Viewer) no Wikipédia ele só esteve disponível até a versão 2010 do Visual Studio.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma alternativa de preferencia da Microsoft para isso no Visual Studio 2012/2013?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De fato o Help Viewer parece descontinuado. Mas existe uma nova versão nova que veio com o Visual Studio 2012: [Microsoft Help Viewer 2.0](http://hv2.helpmvp.com/doc/abouthelpviewer2) (em inglês).

[image]

Mais detalhes: [Blog: Introducing Microsoft Help Viewer 2.0](http://thirdblogfromthesun.com/2013/01/introducing-microsoft-help-viewer-2-0/) (em inglês).

Comment: Este tutorial pode ser útil: http://thirdblogfromthesun.com/2011/05/create-a-basic-help-file-for-the-microsoft-help-viewer/